# Docker Build Error: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1 with NextJS and npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, next.js

I have a NextJS app with the following `Dockerfile.production`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

This is my `docker-compose.production.yml`:

```
services:
  app:
    image: wayve
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

When I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up --build --force-recreate` in my terminal (at the root) I get the following build error:
`failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1`

I do not see any issues with my docker-compose file or my Dockerfile. How can I fix this issue? TYA